# Куда устанавливается postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, centos

Где в centos лежит postgresql? Я не могу найти. Захожу в /. Там есть pgdata. Внутри есть файлики. Но кажется, что это не они, так как при совершении действий над БД, я не вижу изменений в логе.

Comment: /usr/local/pgsql/data

Comment: /var/lib/pgsql/$version

Comment: /var/lib/postgresql/[version]/data/

Comment: да зависит от дистрибутива

Comment: а в чем смысл самому отвечать? Мол знаю и пишу

Comment: @AzizUmarov я делаю заметки себе. По которым потом довольно просто осуществлять навигацию с помощью меток. Иногда заметки полезны. Плюс, иногда люди дают очень хорошие ответы. Как правило, не знаю. А выясняю на ходу.

Comment: @AzizUmarov https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Ainar-G это я знаю меня интересуют доводы конкретного автора. Я видел вольных переводчиков. Увидев к примеру их вопросы я и то вовсе не стараюсь отвечать.

Comment: @AzizUmarov 1. не потерять нить того, что же я делаю, когда разбираюсь в проблеме. Лично для меня это оказывается эффективнее. Затем, получаются полноценные вопросы с исследованием проблемы. 2. Я собираю мою базу знаний.